# The value of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_n}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{(a_{n+p}-a_n)}$$
exists, what's the value of 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_n}{n}}$$

**My attempt**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{(a_{n+p}-a_n)}$$ exists,that is

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}{(a_{n+p}-a_n)}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}{[(a_{n+p}-a_{n+p-1})+(a_{n+p-1}-a_{n+p-2})+...+(a_{n+1}-a_{n})]}\\ &=p\lim_{n\to\infty}{(a_{n+1}-a_{n})}\\ &=\lambda\end{align}$$

We get,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{(a_{n+1}-a_{n})}=\frac{\lambda}{p}$$
By Stolz's theorem,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_n}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{(n+1)-n}=\frac{\lambda}{p}$$

**My question**

Is my answer correct?And if it's wrong? How to prove it?

Comment: You cannot assume the existence of the limit of $a_{n+1} - a_n$, as you can see from the example $a_n = \sin(2\pi n/p)$. Rather, you may open up the proof of Stolz theorem and adapt the argument to this specific case. But of course, the answer itself is right.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for answering my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, one way is to open up the proof of Stolz-Cesàro theorem and apply it to this specific problem. Alternatively, we may rely on the following easy observation:

**Observation.** Let $p \geq 1$ be a positive integer. Then a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ as $n\to\infty$ if and only if, $(x_{pn+r})$ converges to $x$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $r \in \{0, \cdots, p-1\}$.

Now by Stolz-Cesàro theorem, for each $r \in \{0, \cdots, p-1\}$,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{pn+r}}{pn+r}
= \frac{1}{p} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{pn+r}}{n}
= \frac{1}{p} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ a_{pn+r} - a_{p(n-1)+r} \right] = \frac{\lambda}{p}. $$

So, by our observation, $a_n/n \to \lambda/p$ as required.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=a$,$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}}=a$,your proof need this theorem.

Comment: @LiTaichi, Yes, that is the statement of Stolz-Cesàro theorem (which in fact states a more general result). I intended this answer as an alternative to the starting-from-scratch approach that I mentioned in my previous comment.